# Solution of multi variables dependent first order differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, problem-solving

I am solving first order differential equation:
$$(x_0x_1)' =-8 \dfrac{x_0'}{R},$$ where $x_0=f_0(z)$, $x_1=f_1(z)$, $R=r_1-z(r_1-1)=f_2(z)$ (they are all dependent on $z$, but that is not the same dependency).

Also, here first derivative of all variables is derivative along $z$ axis, for example: $x_0' = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x_0}{\mathrm{d}z}$. These are my steps in solving equation:
$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}(x_0x_1) = -\dfrac{8}{R}\dfrac{\mathrm{d} x_0}{\mathrm{d}z} \bigg/*\mathrm{d}z$$

$$\mathrm{d}(x_0x_1) = -\dfrac{8}{R}\mathrm{d} x_0 \bigg/ integration$$
$$x_0 x_1 = - \dfrac{8}{R} x_0 + C$$
$$z=1: x_0 = 1, x_1 = 0\qquad\Rightarrow \qquad0 = - \dfrac{8}{R} + C$$
$$C=\dfrac{8}{R}$$
$$x_1 = \dfrac{8}{R} \left( \dfrac{1}{x_0}-1\right)$$
Did I miss something in solving this equation? Because, when I compare numerical and this solution there is some difference.

[Difference between this-analytical and numerical solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD6Gq.jpg)

Comment: No, that is not correct as $R$ also depends on $z$, is not constant.

Comment: How should I include it in this integration?

Comment: You can't. To see that more precisely, do not do calculus with infinitesimals, write the integrals out and employ the substitution rule of integration that is behind the method of separation of variables.

Comment: Ok, I know substitution rule when in integral there is for example variable t, and dt. But in this case, there is R(z), dx0(z)/dz, what would be substituted by substitution rule? R is not dependent on x0, R is dependent on z, how to connect that?